# 'ReturnList' object has no attribute 'get' in django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a custom render method in DRF , here are my code :

**serializers**

```py
class SupplierSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Supplier
        fields = [
            # "plan",
            "type",
            "created",
            "id",
            "name",
            "bio",
            "established",
            "logo",
            "last_updated",
            "is_active",
            "date_to_pay",
            "mobile",
            "password",
        ]
```

**the Renderer**

```py
class ApiRenderer(BaseRenderer):

    media_type = 'text/plain'
    format = 'txt'

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        response_dict = {
            'status': 'failure',
            'data': {},
            'message': '',
        }
        if data.get('data'):
            response_dict['data'] = data.get('data')
        if data.get('status'):
            response_dict['status'] = data.get('status')
        if data.get('message'):
            response_dict['message'] = data.get('message')
        data = response_dict
        return json.dumps(data)
```

**settings**

```py
RENDERER_CLASSES = (
    'market_control_panel.renderers.ApiRenderer',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',  # <-- And here
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',  # <-- And here
    ],
    # testing ftp upload after comment
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': RENDERER_CLASSES,

}
```

But I get this error when I try to open any API link :

```
'ReturnList' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

The **`data`** parameter of **`render(...)`** method can be anything, such as, `list`, `dict`, `string` `float`, etc. This **`data`** is returned by your view (function or class) and you should expect it to be anything.

In your case, the view ***may*** returned a ***list*** like response (assuming that you have accessed a *list view*) and hence the returned object doesn't support a **`.get()`** method and hence the error.

I am not sure what you are up to, but, you should consider this while updating the render logic.